# How to create Google calendar and share for multiple user using google calendar api

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I want to create a Google calendar using the Google Calendar API and share it with **multiple users** (in C#).

[Google Calendar API v2 Developer's Guide: .NET](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pay attention to [this section](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet#AddAcl) of the referenced doc.

**EDIT:**
The original link is no longer valid, please refer to the [Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing) document.

Comment: Could this be the link instead https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing ?